# "Expression does not produce a value" in javascript, vb.net

Tags: javascript, .net, vb.net

In the Create View of the "Deal" model, I've defined a javascript function that creates a new object in a List Property when clicking a button.

I get the error "expression does not produce a value". I'm not expecting a value, I only need to create a new empty object in the list, so I don't understand this error.

javascript in my view, the line that adds the new Period to the list throws the error:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addRow() {
        @Model.Periods.Add(New DealPeriod());
        ...
    }
</script>
```

"Deal" Model:

```
Public MustInherit Class Deal

    ...

    <Display(name:="Periodos")>
    Public Property Periods As New List(Of DealPeriod)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here - to cover the issue in the question "expression does not produce a value":

The `@`symbol here means *"output the result of the following to the http response stream"*.

As `List.Add()` returns void, there is nothing to send to the response stream, so it gives you that error message.

Put another way, the `@` needs a value and `List.Add()` does not generate a value.

The second issue is that it appears you are mixing server-side execute with client-side execution (note I don't say server-side/client-side code, that's allowed in a similar way to how you have it).  It appears you want to add a new "DealPeriod" when "addRow" is called - that's simply not how it works.  The VB.Net code runs on the server and the javascript code runs on the client, in the browser.  They are not linked together.

There are ways to link them such as an ajax call or signalr.

Comment: Thanks, @freedomn-m, for helping me to clarify the"@"meaning. I thought Ajax would be necessary, but i was following this tutorial, where it's performed a similar call. I'll use Ajax.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/766214/List-Model-Binding-in-MVC

Answer (score 1):

You are expecting `@Model.Periods.Add(New DealPeriod());` to run when that javascript function is called, but that is not what is  happening. The inline VB code is run server-side before sending HTML to the client. 
With your webpage open, view source of the page and observe the code that gets rendered in that javascript function. You will not see that line of code.
What you want to do is make an ajax call to a controller that will perform the logic you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Crowcoder. I thought Ajax would be necessary, but i was following this tutorial, where it's performed a similar call. I'll use Ajax.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/766214/List-Model-Binding-in-MVC